# LuaLaTeX creates an `.ind` file. Why?

Tags: luatex, indexing, makeindex

When I run `lualatex` on one of my files, not only is a `.idx` file created, but also a `.ind` file. Why is it so? I thought it was the job of the external `makeindex` program to create an `.ind` file based on the `.idx` file generated by a previous LaTeX run.

Comment: Your editor has done it for you. Look into the configuration of your editor!

Comment: If you use e.g. imakeidx makeindex is called in the background, check the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, you were right. Thanks! Does this mean that if I use `imakeidx` I don't need to call the external `makeindex` program separately?

Comment: Yes, makeindex is one of the safe applications that engines like pdftex or luatex can call directly and imakeidx makes use of this.

Comment: Regarding `imakeidx`, if you have a special page layout for the first page of the index, you may have to use the `[original]` option, and then you may have to run `makeindex` separately.